# How to update the colour of minColor and maxColor when data is changed in high charts' solid gauge in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

Basically, I want to implement https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid in ReactJS. I set `minColor` and `maxColor` in config, which is if the speed is between 40 and 60 showing green and otherwise showing red. The charts show normally in the right colour initially. I also `setInterval` to update the chart in function `_testSoloution`. The figure changed but the colour isn't updated. How to update the colour?

```js
import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more';
import SolidGauge from 'highcharts/modules/solid-gauge';

const gaugeSetting = (data) => {
    return {
        chart: {
            type: 'solidgauge'
        },
        title: null,
        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '85%'],
            size: '140%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            minColor: data >= 40 && data < 60 ? 'green' : 'red',
            maxColor: data >= 60 || data <= 40 ? 'red' : 'green',
            lineWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickPixelInterval: 400,
            tickWidth: 0,
            title: {
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            },
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: -30,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
            data: [data],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">°C</span></div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' km/h'
            }
        }]
    }
}
export default class Chart extends Component{
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            cars: [
                {   
                    name: 'Car1',
                    speed: 30,
                },
                {   
                    name: 'Car2',
                    speed: 50,
                },
            ]
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
        SolidGauge(Highcharts);
        this.charts = this.state.cars.map((car, index) => {
            return Highcharts.chart(this.refs[car.name], gaugeSetting(car.speed));
        })
        this.timerID = setInterval(() => {
            this._testSoloution(0);
            
        }, 1000);
        console.log(this.refs.chart);
    }

    _testSoloution = (index) => {
        point = chartSpeed.series[0].points[0];
        inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
        newVal = point.y + inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
 
        this.setState({
            cars: [
                ...this.state.cars.slice(0,index),
                {
                    ...this.state.cars[index],
                    speed: newVal
                },
                ...this.state.cars.slice(index + 1),
            ]
        })

    }
    _showGuage = () => (
        this.state.cars.map(car => (
                <div ref={car.name} style={{width:300, height:200, float: 'left'}}></div>
            )
        )
    )

    render() {
        return (
            
            <div style={{width:'100%', margin: '0 auto', display:'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', justifyContent:'center'}}>
                {this._showGuage()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where do you try to change the color?

Comment: I set the criteria in yAxis.minColor, and yAxis.maxColor in gaugeSetting, and then in function _testSoloution, I invoke point.update(newVal) when a new value come. The color should change when the new value falls out of the criteria.

Comment: newVal is just the y co-ordinate and point must expect both x and y. There is something fishy there.

Comment: According to the example, https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid, newValue makes the figure change and the color change.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts supports only hex colors when it comes to some numerical operations on them, so colors like `red` or `green` won't work in this case. Use `#FF0000` and `#008000` instead.

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/global.html#ColorString

**Doc reference:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors